# Python concurrent.futures.wait job submission order not preserved

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Does python's `concurrent.futures.wait()` preserve the order of job submission?
I submitted two jobs to `ThreadPoolExecutor` as follows:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time, random

def mult(n):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,5))
    return f"mult: {n * 2}"

def divide(n):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,5))
    return f"divide: {n // 2}"


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    mult_future = executor.submit(mult, 200)
    divide_future = executor.submit(divide, 200)

    # wait for both task to complete
    mult_task, divide_task = concurrent.futures.wait(
        [mult_future, divide_future],
        return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED,
    ).done

    mult_result = mult_task.result()
    divide_result = divide_task.result()

    print(mult_result)
    print(divide_result)
```

Sometimes I see

```
divide: 50
mult: 400
```

and sometimes,

```
mult: 400
divide: 50
```

shouldn't `mult_task, divide_task` always map to `mult_future, divide_future` ?

```
python --version
>> Python 3.8.16
```

Comment: When a function isn't working as expected, it's always good to read its documentation.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) that the function  `wait()`:

> Returns a named 2-tuple of sets.

By definition, sets are unordered. That means you cannot guarantee the order.

Since you already have `mult_future` and `divide_future`, you can use them to guarantee the order. There is no need to call `wait` either.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time


def mult(n):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5))
    return f"mult: {n * 2}"


def divide(n):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5))
    return f"divide: {n // 2}"


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    mult_future = executor.submit(mult, 200)
    divide_future = executor.submit(divide, 200)

# Print in order: mult div
print(mult_future.result())
print(divide_future.result())
```

Comment: Oh really! does that mean it'd block until `.result()` is ready?

Comment: @DevEx yes, it blocks until result is ready, `futures.wait` is usually used when you want to wait for the first one to complete when you don't know which one will complete first.

Answer (score 4):

[futures.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) returns two sets, items in the set are ordered based on their address in memory because `Future` doesn't define a comparison operation, so the return order **has nothing to do with the input order**.

if you want to loop over outputs in input order then just loop over the input list.

```
in_vals = [mult_future, divide_future]
concurrent.futures.wait(
        in_vals,
        return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED,
    ).done
for item in in_vals:
    ...
```